# How to extract and count in certain condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have two policy data like below.

```
   enroll    lapse
A 2010/2/1   2013/1/2
B 2012/3/1   2013/1/4
```

I would like to count the number who policies are ongoing at the beginning of the year.

```
    enroll    lapse      year
A   2010/2/1  2013/1/2  2011/1/1
A   2010/2/1  2013/1/2  2012/1/1
A   2010/2/1  2013/1/2  2013/1/1
B   2012/3/1  2013/1/4  2013/1/1
```

and count these ongoing policies.

```
year  num
2011   1
2012   1
2013   2
```

I guess I must use query method. but I couldnt figure out.

Comment: This data from Database table or which format it is ?

Comment: in what date format is `2012/1/4` after `2012/3/1` ?

Comment: sorry dataformat is datetime!

Comment: @Heisenberg Turns out I misunderstood your question, so I deleted my answer. Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
#convert columns to datetimes
df['enroll'] = pd.to_datetime(df['enroll'])
df['lapse'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lapse'])
```

For each row apply function for expand rows, reshape to Series and join to original `df`:

```
def f(x):
    b = x['lapse'].year - x['enroll'].year 
    return (pd.Series(pd.date_range(x['enroll'], periods=b, freq='AS')))

s = df.apply(f, axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('year')

df = df.join(s)
print (df)
      enroll      lapse       year
A 2010-02-01 2013-01-02 2011-01-01
A 2010-02-01 2013-01-02 2012-01-01
A 2010-02-01 2013-01-02 2013-01-01
B 2012-03-01 2013-01-04 2013-01-01
```

Another solution:

```
#create start year
df['year'] = df['enroll'] + pd.offsets.YearBegin(0) 
#count repeating
a = df['lapse'].dt.year - df['enroll'].dt.year
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index, a)]
#add year offset 
df['a'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df["year"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["year"] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=x['a']), axis=1)
df = df.drop('a', 1)
print (df)
      enroll      lapse       year
A 2010-02-01 2013-01-02 2011-01-01
A 2010-02-01 2013-01-02 2012-01-01
A 2010-02-01 2013-01-02 2013-01-01
B 2012-03-01 2013-01-04 2013-01-01
```

And last:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['year'].dt.year).size().reset_index(name='num')
print (df1)
   year  num
0  2011    1
1  2012    1
2  2013    2
```

Comment: Have I misunderstood the question? This seems like a complicated answer.

Comment: It seems yes, unfortunately :(

Comment: Fair enough... answer has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

first read your policy data, line by line.

```
   enroll    lapse
A 2010/2/1   2013/1/2
B 2012/3/1   2012/1/4
```

and then put each line into function count.
dictionary result might be the one you want ?
If there's any misunderstanding of your question, please let me know.

```
result = {}
def count(start, end):
    start = [int(i) for i in start.split('/')]
    start = datetime.date(*start)
    end = [int(i) for i in end.split('/')]
    end = datetime.date(*end)
    delta = end - start
    new = start + datetime.timedelta(delta.days)
    for i in range(1, new.year - start.year + 1):
        result[start.year + i] = result.setdefault(start.year + i, 0) + 1


a = count('2010/2/1', '2013/1/2')
b = count('2012/3/1', '2013/1/4')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pd.daterange`

```
start = pd.Timestamp(year=df['enroll'].dt.year.min() + 1, month=1, day=1)
end = pd.Timestamp(year=df['lapse'].dt.year.max(), month=12, day=31)

for year in pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='AS'):
    print(year, ((df['enroll'] < year) & (df['lapse'] > year)).sum())
```

> ```
> 2011-01-01 00:00:00 1
> 2012-01-01 00:00:00 1
> 2013-01-01 00:00:00 2
> ```

```
data = {year.year: ((df['enroll'] < year) & (df['lapse'] > year)).sum() for year in pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='AS')}
pd.Series(data)
```

> ```
> 2011    1
> 2012    1
> 2013    2
> dtype: int64
> ```